# Javascript code works only for current open page of pagination

Tags: javascript

I have a select dropdown in PHP codeigniter like below, in the first column of each row of a table.

```
<select class="form-control"; name="residance_select">
  <option <?php if($d == 'native') { echo 'selected'; }?> value='native' >native</option>
  <option <?php if($d == 'migrated') { echo 'selected'; }?> value='migrated' >migrated</option>
</select>
```

Then in my **javascript** code I check if any of the select is having value set to **migrated**  using the code below:

```
jQuery("select[name='residance_select']").each(function() {
if(this.value == 'migrated')
{
    // some action
}
});
```

I also use pagination for the table. If I am on page one and page two have any select set to **migrated**. then my javascript does not check values on the second page. It checks only on current page if any of select is set to **migrated**.

Comment: second page won't be loaded in the document or current page..Javascript will handle the DOM which is exist in the document.

Comment: I used bootstrap datatable. values are already loaded divided in pagination

Comment: ok give class name and try with class name instead of name

Comment: @ lalithkumar I got it javascript can not read it. I need to find some other way then

Comment: No it is not working with class name. You are correct JS can not read it

Comment: Then you need to do with back end technology